# Get Dropdown SelectedValue using Datalist OnItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am trying to get Dropdownlist selected value using Datalist OnItemDataBound.

DlSubjects is main DataList and dlTests is nested DataList. dropdownlist is included with dlSubjects.
My code :

```
protected void dlSubjects_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataList dlTests = e.Item.FindControl("dlTests") as DataList;
        DropDownList drpTopic = e.Item.FindControl("drpTopic") as DropDownList;

        string Value = drpTopic.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me regarding this ???

Comment: So what is the problem or the exception? Is `dlTests` a nested `DataList` in `dlSubjects`?

Comment: yes, so based on dropdown selected value, i will filter dlTests.

Comment: I am nt getting any exception, but it is not giving me selected value. It is giving default selected value of dropdownlist.

Comment: dropdown is included with dlSubjects which is main DataList.

Comment: then you're databinding the datalist also on postbacks. Wrap the databinding stuff in page_load in a `!IsPostBack` check.

Comment: on dropdownselectedindex changed, I am binding dlSubjects to fire onItemDataBound. Am i doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Im tooooooo late, but Im doing same thing right now, if Im right, then I think answer should be something like that:

```
protected void dlSubjects_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataList dlTests = e.Item.FindControl("dlTests") as DataList;
        DropDownList drpTopic = e.Item.FindControl("drpTopic") as DropDownList;

        string Value = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[index].ToString(); //index is your dropdown index in the datalist
    }
}
```